# generics struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

I have a generic class like this

```
public abstract class GenericBaseClass<T extends GenericBaseVO> extends Base
{
    protected T filter;

    public T getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    public void setFilter(T filter) {
        this.filter= filter;
    }
}
```

I have a second class like this:

```
public class MyClass extends GenericBaseClass<MyVO> 
{
}
```

And I have an action like this:

```
<action name="MyAction" class="MyClass">

</action>
```

When I do a submit in a form to execute `MyAction`, the object that came to set filter is of `GenericBaseVO` type and not of `MyVO` type. Why? What can I do to  correct this?

Comment: Which classes are `GenericBaseVO` and `MyVO`? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: MyVO extends from GenericBaseVO. They are two search filters. MyVO is a more specific filter. I'm trying to do some actions on base class with GenericBaseVO variables. This actions are the same for all search pages but each specific search have more search fields and so I define my class using <MyVO>. I need to save all search fields that I have on my jsp an so I need to save a MyVO object, but when I have submit the action skip prepare and goes to Base Class  setFilter whith a GenericBaseVO object.